# On hover on the parent div, Change the color of all the child div as well as parent background color

Tags: html, css

I need to change the button color and text color on hover on the parent div.

I am getting the output and on hover, I have to change the color.

[image]
[image]

Would you help me out?

```css
.Set {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 35px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 450px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.btn {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.btn_bg {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.Set:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="Set">
  <h2 class="textMe">adasdsad asdas d</h2>
  <div class="bigtextMe">
    <p>asdsa asdsd asd asd sd sd sd </p>
    <a href="" class="btn btn_bg">njkndkajnsdkja</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Yes, I checked that but my scenario is different. I am also changing the background color of the parent.

Comment: Accepted answer changing the only one child I have more than one.

Comment: so make it same for all elements you want to change on hover

Comment: Try these lines of code in your CSS file `.Set:hover .textMe{
  color: #fff;
}
.Set:hover .btn{
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.Set:hover p{
  color: #fff;
}`

Comment: @Usman, Yes, It's working. after using your code

Comment: the accepted answer and the other answer will not give you a *ready-to-copy-paste* code, you need to do a small effort to understand the different selector and try. I don't think it's something you can do in only 2min (if I consider your reply after me closing the question)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Before uploading the question I checked that link you shared. I was confused about the multiple hovers. I thought there is another way to handle the multiple hovers on the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the a tag with the descendant operator

```
.Set:hover >.bigtextMe > .btn_bg{}
```

```css
.Set {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 35px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 450px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.btn {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.btn_bg {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.Set:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color:white
}
.Set:hover >.bigtextMe > .btn_bg{
  background-color: white;
  color:black
}
```

```html
<div class="Set">
  <h2 class="textMe">adasdsad asdas d</h2>
  <div class="bigtextMe">
    <p>asdsa asdsd asd asd sd sd sd </p>
    <a href="" class="btn btn_bg">njkndkajnsdkja</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you assist me with .Set:hover >.bigtextMe > .btn_bg{} ?

Comment: It means on hover of the element with class **set** select the child of it having class bigtext and in turn select the child with class btn_bg to get the a. change the color and background

Comment: Yes, your code is also working. Thanks for the help.